# Skip run confirmation

Tags: python

When I run a script via GUI, e.g. in Python, I get  dialog asking me to confirm that I want to run it or display it. Is there a way i can set this not to happen, and to run it straight from click?

Answer (score 3):

There sure is. Open Nautilus, then click Edit -> Preferences. On the Behavior tab, select "Run executable text files when they are opened".
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Does this make it run in the terminal or just run?

Comment: I believe it just runs w/o terminal.